# Meteor Store Image URL as Avatar

Tags: image, file, meteor, amazon-s3, upload

I have an image uploader that uses amazon s3 to store files. I am trying to update my users.avatar value to the amazon url upon upload.

Here is my upload event:

```
Template.avatarUpload.events({
"click button.upload": function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    var files = $("input.avatar-upload")[0].files

    S3.upload({
            files: files,
            path: "avatars"
        }, function(e,r) {
            console.log(r);
    });
  }
})
```

I tried something like the following based on a few other stackoverflow QA's:

First this, but then I ran into a problem where I couldn't store files.url without getting an error (update failed: MongoError: '$set' is empty. You must specify a field like so: {$mod: {: ...}})

```
Meteor.users.update({_id:Meteor.user()._id}, {$set:{"profile.name": files.url}})
```

Then like this:

```
var set = {avatar: {}};
    set.avatar[files.url];

    Meteor.users.update({
      _id: Meteor.user()._id
    }, {$set: set});
```

But no luck. Basically trying to take the URL and store it in users.avatar. My json looks like this:

```
users = [{
  username: "normcore",
  avatar: "avatar_url"
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how we got it working. I'll leave this here for anyone having the same issue:

Client side:

```
Template.avatarUpload.events({
"click button.upload": function(){
    event.preventDefault();
    var files = $("input.avatar-upload")[0].files


    S3.upload({
            files: files,
            path: "avatars"
        }, function(e,r) {
            console.log(r);
            console.log(Meteor.user());
            var user = Meteor.user();
            var student = {"_id": user._id };
            console.log(student);
            var url = r.secure_url;
            Meteor.call('updateAvatar', student, url, function(error) {
                if (error) {
                  return console.log(error);
                } else {
                  return console.log('success');
                }
            });
    });
}
});
Template.avatarUpload.helpers({
"files": function(){
    return S3.collection.find();
}
});
```

Server Side:

```
Meteor.methods({
    updateAvatar: function(user, url) {
    console.log(user);
    check(user, {
      _id: String
    });
    check(url, String);

    return Meteor.users.update({_id:Meteor.user()._id},
      {
        $set: {
          "profile.avatar": url
         }
      }, function(error) {
        if (error) {
          return console.log(error);
        }
      });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Post the whole code for the helper.

Overall, this is something your code should look like:

```
Template.avatarUpload.events({
    "click button.upload": function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        var files = $("input.avatar-upload")[0].files
        S3.upload({
            files: files,
            path: "avatars"
        }, function(e,r) {
            if(e) {
                console.log(r);
            } else if(r) {
                console.log(r);
                Meteor.users.update(Meteor.user(), {$set: {avatar: r.url}}); // Correct this to actual URL in response. If multiple files 
            }
        });
    },
})
```

You'll have to figure out how to handle the case of multiple files upload. One way is to not enable multi in your input tag.

Comment: Ok so now I've found out that it's not going to be good to do this fully client sided, I'll put the code in an edit above to show how I am trying to go about it.

Comment: It won't really work with the way Allows/Deny's are setup for the usergroup for this project